# Creating fragments in 2.2 - create an assessment viewer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have written code for creating a question viewer where there are 20 questions, each with 4 radio button options. There are two buttons prev and next. Now I want a small fragment on the left which shows me all question numbers and if i answer a question it changes the colour on the button on the fragment. Also if i click that button it takes me to that question. I have created methods for retrieving the questions from a sqlite file. How do I convert this to include the fragment. I have installed the compatibility package. But how do I proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be quite easy in the end. I just had to make two different fragments for the question numbers on the left, and the questions on the right, Move my business logic to the fragment, extend Fragment Activity instead of Activity and inflate the fragment on landscape orientation. :)